# Two different classes inherit from an abstract class. How to insert them into a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have abstract class IIdentifiers, as well as classes Areas : IIdentifiers, Regions : IIdentifiers.
I am getting an exception "Unable to convert from "System.Collections.Generic.List <Net45MVC.Areas>" to "Net45MVC.Abstract.IIdentifiers""

```
var CollectionSelectionTables = new Dictionary<string, List<IIdentifiers>>;
CollectionSelectionTables.Add("areas", areas);
```

Comment: Please don't name classes with plural names. If your class is a collection of Area, call it AreaCollection, not Areas etc. Properties are named in plural form when they are collections, so if you have a property that is a `List<Areas>` it would be `public List<Areas> Areass` (or Areases) which starts to get confusing/ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this:

```
var aList = new List<Areas>();
List<IIdentifiers> iList = aList;
```

even though Areas is-a IIdentifers. If you could do thatit would mean you end up with an iList that looks like it will accept any class that is-a IIdentifiers but actually it will only accept Areas. What would happen if you tried to put a Regions into it? It looks like it should take it, right? Because on the surface it's a `List<IIdentifiers>`, but actually inside it's a `List<Areas>` and a Regions is not an Areas

For more in depth discussion on it, read up on contravariance and covariance

---

But you can do this if you're making a new list :

```
var aList = new List<Areas>();
List<IIdentifiers> iList = new List<IIdentifiers>(aList);
```

passing the list of Areas into the constructor will cause the IIdentifiers list to put all the Areas in the passed-in list into itself as an initial collection.

Or this if you're adding to an existing list:

```
var aList = new List<Areas>();
List<IIdentifiers> iList = new();

iList.AddRange(aList);
```

---

In your code that is filling the dictionary, you can use these options depending on whether the dictionary entry is being added for the first time or existing

```
var aList = (... some list of Areas ...)

//existing dictionary entry
d[someKey].AddRange(aList);

//new dictionary entry
d[someKey] = new List<IIdentifiers>(aList);
```

Comment: thanx, i corrected: static List<IIdentifiers> areas = new List<IIdentifiers>();

Answer (score 0):

You should use covariant collection, such as IEnumerable.
See more: [Covariance and contravariance in generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) [Covariance and Contravariance (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/)

```
public class SomeClass
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<BaseClass>>();
            var childCollection = new List<ChildClass>();
            dictionary.Add("childCollection", childCollection);
        }
    }
    
public class BaseClass { }

public class ChildClass : BaseClass { }
```